# How do I correctly use h2 tags given that Google says to not overuse them?

Tags: seo, html5

I am confused about when I should use a h2 tag and when I should avoid it.

Like most commercial websites I have a **product list** page. 24 products are divided into 6 rows of 4 columns each. The product is displayed in a 'card'. I am doubting if each card title (so each product title) should be a h2 tag or if it should be just a p tag.

On one hand, **24 h2 tags** seems like overuse to me.
On the other hand, each product is just as important as the next one, and it is the main content of the page. I would like to know what is the correct approach in this instance.

Besides products I also have a blog page, where I often write articles in the form of "5 tips do task x". Each subheading is a h2 tag. Is this also overuse or is it correct use?

Comment: Try semantic tags, with a section tag for each product.

Comment: “You can use H1 tags as often as you want on a page. There’s no limit, neither upper or lower bound. Your site is going to rank perfectly fine with no H1 tags or with five H1 tags.” - John Mueller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my understanding, there should be one h1 title on the top of the page and then h2 titles over main (sub-)sections of a page. Under each h2 heading comes the content, which should be more than just 1 item or 1 sentance usually.

When you have a list of products in tabular format as you describe it, putting h2 for each of 24 product seems to be overdoing it.

I suppose your goal is to make it possible to search for each of these products and for that putting its name in h2 might be useful.

If you changed your page so that the table can have sections for each product which can be opened up (e.g. with summary details tags on the same page or via hyperlink on a new page) then there is a place to put the product as a heading, as you provide a lot of details to your product.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing an essay and use 20 `<h2>` tags, then it is fine.  Thats what they are for.

But for a product list, I would suggest that it is overuse.  You don't need to use `<h2>` tags for the titles, they can just be text formatted to look like titles.  Or as suggested, you could use `<section>` tags.

> **<section>: The Generic Section element**
> The  HTML element represents a generic standalone section of a document, which doesn't have a more specific semantic element to represent it. Sections should always have a heading, with very few exceptions.

From [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section)

Answer (score 0):

For 12 years I optimized a lot of sites and never had that google for H tags somehow penalized my sites.

Do everything in moderation, so that it would be visually beautiful and structurally clear on the page. Then everything will be "ok"